# WordPress Export returns an empty CSV

Tags: wordpress, export-to-csv, ninja-forms

Trying to Export ninja form submissions with WordPress bulk action or download all the submissions button,
it returns/downloads as an empty CSV file.
the console has the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/csv: "https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?..."
```

[image]

any thoughts? thanks in advance.

Comment: ```download all the submissions button``` is a custom functionality that you've written yourself? or is it part of the ```ninja forms``` itself?

Comment: it's a part of the ninja form itself

Comment: it was a problem with the server PHP setting,

inside MultiPHP INI Editor, "zlib.output_compression" should be disabled.